# Why did kafka-connect resend all messages on this config change?

Tags: apache-kafka-connect

We are using Kakfa connect with a `JdbcSourceConnector` for fetching events from a simple outbox table in PostgreSQL to push them to Kafka. The connector was previously configured as follows:

```
"mode": "incrementing",
"incrementing.column.name": "id",
"query": "SELECT * FROM outbox",
```

We wanted to add a delay and changed the configuration to:

```
"mode": "timestamp+incrementing",
"incrementing.column.name": "id",
"timestamp.column.name": "created",
"timestamp.delay.interval.ms": 10000,
"timestamp.initial": -1,
"db.timezone": "Europe/Vienna",
```

It all works well now but for some reason **our whole outbox got replayed when we applied this configuration**. This was not what we expected because the [documenation](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/jdbc/current/source-connector/source_config_options.html) states that `timestamp.initial` is

> The epoch timestamp (in milliseconds) used for initial queries that use timestamp criteria. Use -1 to use the current time. If not specified, all data will be retrieved.

And as you see above, we configured `timestamp.initial` accordingly.

So how can this behavior be explained? Why did kafka-connect decide to resend all messages, even though their timestamp was definitely before the current time?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen for multiple reasons.

- For the first restart of the connector after the change that you have made, it might have triggered a reinitialization, and the **timestamp.initial** would be set to the **current time**.This could have caused the connector to reprocess all data.
- Make sure that the **db.timezone** is set correctly to match the timezone used in your database's "created" column. Timestamps may be interpreted differently if there is a timezone mismatch.
- Check the **precision** of the timestamp data in the "created" column of your PostgreSQL table. If the timestamp values have high precision, there might be a difference between the initial timestamp and the data's actual timestamps.

Comment: Can you explain your first point in more detail? That's what I would have expected, that the initial timestamp is set to the current time. But I then would also expect that elements older than this timestamp (e.g. one with a timestamp one week ago) are not even being loaded by the SQL query and thus cannot be pushed to Kafka.

Comment: The first scenario might happen if the timestamp.initial:-1  is not been considered by the connector, try to get the config of the connector that is running with the rest API 
"curl -i -X GET -H  "Content-Type:application/json" \ http://localhost:8083/connectors/theconnector/config", if the config  timestamp.initial is set to -1, then you need to check the other factors.

Comment: The config is now `timestamp.initial: "-1"` (with quotes, but I guess that's fine; it's always with quotes, even if I send it without).

Comment: The other two issues would still not explain, why a one month old message got replayed. Or do they?

Comment: The "timestamp.initial" parameter is expected to be a long, ( https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/jdbc/current/source-connector/source_config_options.html ), this might be causing the unexpected behavior.

Comment: It\s not me who makes it a String. I pass it as Long, Kafka returns it as String.